# form_for redirect to show instead of create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form for my actions new and update.

All is ok for update but for my new, he tries to redirect me to show instead of create.

I have this error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"club/team", :club_id=>"1"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Here my form:

```
 <%= form_for @team, :html => { :class => 'sky-form', :multipart => true }, url: club_team_path do |f| %>

 ...

 <% end %>
```

And here my routes :

```
club_team_index POST     /clubs/:club_id/team(.:format)                club/team#create
new_club_team   GET      /clubs/:club_id/team/new(.:format)            club/team#new
edit_club_team  GET      /clubs/:club_id/team/:id/edit(.:format)       club/team#edit
club_team       GET      /clubs/:club_id/team/:id(.:format)            club/team#show
                PATCH    /clubs/:club_id/team/:id(.:format)            club/team#update
                PUT      /clubs/:club_id/team/:id(.:format)            club/team#update
                DELETE   /clubs/:club_id/team/:id(.:format)            club/team#destroy
```

My controller code :

```
class Club::TeamController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @teams = Team.find_all_by_club_id(params[:club_id])
  end

  def new
    @categories = TeamCategory.all
    @levels = TeamLevel.all
    @club = Club.find(params[:club_id])
  end

  def create
    if !user_signed_in?
      flash[:errors] = []
      flash[:errors] << {:message => 'Vous devez vous connecter pour créer une Equipe', :strong => 'Accès Refusé :'}
      redirect_to new_club_path
    else
      @team = Team.new(team_params)
      @team.club_id = params[:club_id]

      if @team.save
        redirect_to club_team_path(@team.club_id, @team.id)
      else
        flash[:errors] = []
        flash[:errors] << {:message => 'Des champs sont mal remplis', :strong => "Erreur :"}

        redirect_to new_club_team_path
      end
    end
  end

  def show
    @team = Team.find_by_id(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @team = Team.find(params[:id])
    @categories = TeamCategory.all
    @levels = TeamLevel.all
    @club = Club.find(params[:club_id])
  end

  def update
    @team = Team.find(params[:id])

    if @team.update(team_params)
      flash[:success] = []
      flash[:success] << {:message => 'Equipe mise à jour avec succès.', :strong => 'Edition :'}
      redirect_to club_team_path(@team.club_id, @team.id)
    else
      flash[:errors] = []
      flash[:errors] << {:message => 'Certain champs ne remplissent pas les conditions requises.', :strong => 'Erreur :'}
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private
    def team_params
      params.require(:team).permit(:name, :category_id, :level_id, :avatar)
    end
end
```

Comment: remove the url part and use [@club, @team] in the form_for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here in this line

```
<%= form_for @team, :html => { :class => 'sky-form', :multipart => true }, url: club_team_path do |f| %>
```

When you write `url:club_team_path`,as per the routes,it matches the show action.

Change it to like this

```
<%= form_for [@club,@team], :html => { :class => 'sky-form', :multipart => true } do |f| %>
```

For more details,see this **[API](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for)**

Comment: I have this error : First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty. I set my club with : @club = Club.find(params[:club_id])

Comment: I hade my controller bellow

Comment: @user2847607 Add `@team = Team.new` in your `new` method.

Comment: Now : undefined method `club_teams_path' for #<#<Class:0x0000010aef20f8>:0x0000010aef0ff0> my route is club_team_path but he generate it with a 's'

Comment: The problem was in routes.rb, I renamed resources :team to :teams and it's ok now. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @JoePae Glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok the probleme was in my routes file.

I had

```
 # Clubs routes
  scope module: 'club' do
    resources :clubs do
      resources :team, :only => [:show, :new, :create, :update, :destroy, :edit]
      get '/club_accounting', to: 'club_accounting#index', as: 'club_accounting_index'
      post '/club_accounting', to: 'club_accounting#create', as: 'club_accounting_create'
      delete '/club_accounting/:id', to: 'club_accounting#delete', as: 'club_accounting_delete'
    end
  end
```

I renamed :team to :teams and all is ok now !

Thanks